# How to reconstruct phase data from magnitude only data in a frequency domain function?

Tags: audio, transfer-function, data, phase

I'm trying to do a reverse-engineering a software called LEAP from the now disappeared LinearX company. This software can perform an operation called "Minimum Phase Transform". This takes real/magnitude only data in a voltage vs frequency curve that is supposed to be the frequency-response of a transfer function, and produces the full complex data curve, by adding the phase data. Assuming the system is minimum phase.

Curves are frequency domain, with logarithmic scale/spacing for frequency axis, frequency domain is the audio frequency range, 10Hz to 40000 Hz. Typically, the curves have about 400 data points.

The curves are stored and processed as tables of values. For example a bandpass filter tuned at 1KHz:

```
Frequency Voltage 

10 Hz     -40 dBV
10.21 Hz  -39.82 dBV
...
1 KHz      0 dBV
...
40 KHz      -32.04 dBV
```

The goal is taking a curve like this:

[image: Voltage curve with no phase data]

Voltage curve with no phase data.

and producing this:

[image: Voltage curve with phase data]

Voltage curve with phase data.

It seems this software uses the Hilbert transform. As is stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_phase):

$$\arg\left[H(j\omega)\right] = -\mathcal{H}\{\log|H(j\omega)|\}$$

It needs to know the slopes/derivatives at both extremes of the curve, the low frequency extreme and the high frequency extreme in dB/oct. The program asks the user for the two slope numbers or tries to estimate them automatically.

I'm trying to reproduce this operation with C# language in a simple desktop program, or with a simple Excel spreadsheet, but I have no success at all.

My question is, what could be the algorithm for performing this operation? I'm having trouble for trying to apply the Hilbert transform. I do not know how to perform an improper definite integral from 0Hz to infinity Hz with discrete finite-range data.

It seems that the transform has an alternate notation, that is the convolution of \$f(\omega)\$ and \$g(\omega) = 1/(\pi \omega)\$. Again, I have no clue how to do it programatically. Perhaps I could make a discrete convolution, but what range or window should I give to \$g(\omega)\$?

How can I do this?, How can I find the phase curve from the magnitude curve, with discrete data points in the frequency domain?

Comment: I suspect your question is much broader and that you want to encompass curves far more complex. But the one you present to me just looks to me like a 2nd order with \$\zeta=0.5\$ (or \$Q=1\$.) That makes the phase trivial. But I honestly can't answer the question about the Hilbert transform as I'm not exactly sure what minimum-phase in this case actually means. Does it mean, as appears shown, that the sum of the phase from specified minimum to specified maximum tends to zero? Anyway, for 2nd order per above curve, the only variable under modification is \$\zeta\$. And that's 0.5 here.

Comment: Try plotting \$\mathcal{H}_s=\frac{6283.18531\,s}{s^2+6283.18531\,s +39478417.6}\$, where \$\sigma=0\$ and \$\therefore s=j\omega\$. Should be close.

Comment: I have converted your image and text mathematical expressions to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (edit may be pending).  Please check that I did so correctly.

Comment: thanks for taking a time. Yes I want to process any kind of curve, the example I shown is Q=1 1st order bandpass. Minimum Phase system means the system has all zeros have the real part negative, in other words, all zeroes are in the left half of the s-plane

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with an FFT by making the Cepstrum causal (which is admittedly a mouthful).

1. Take the natural logarithm of the magnitude
2. Do an inverse FFT (which is the Cepstrum)
3. Make it causal: double the values t>0 , set the values at t<0 to zero and leave t=0 and t=N/2 alone
4. Do a forward FFT. The real part is the log magnitude, the imaginary part is the minimum phase (in radians).
5. Take the exponential to get transfer function in linear units

There are a few alternatives to this:

1. Frequency domain filtering: Hilbert transform is simply a 90 degree phase shift, i.e the transfer function is \$H(\omega) = j*sign(\omega)\$
   , where $sign$ is the signum function
2. Time domain filtering. Create the transfer function from step 1 on a suitable FFT grid and do an inverse FFT to get an impulse response. Rotate and window and than apply as an FIR filter.

Doing this in a computer adds the complexity that you have discrete signals in both domains which are periodic with the sample rate and FFT length respectively and that  frequency domain multiplication implements circular convolution, not linear one.

Recommend reading on discrete Hilbert Transform: http://andrewduncan.net/air/

Comment: There was also a [correction published by the author](https://www.aes.org/images/e-lib/thumbnails/6/0/6097_full.png).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly your proposed solution has a unwanted side effect. Converting the TF to time domain, and back to frequency domain with FFT makes the result curve to have linear-spaced frequency points. That causes to have poor resolution at low frequencies, and too much resolution at high frequencies. I need to preserve the log spaced frequency axis points (or even irregular spaced points). With log spacing we have good resolution at both extremes of the audio frequency range. That means we must work on the frequency domain only and directly.